# Compute $H_k=\lim_{ n \to \infty }\frac{P_k(n)}{P_k({n-1})}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $k$ be a positive interger number, and define the sequence $\{P_k(n)\}_n$ as: $P_k(0)=0$, $P_k(1)=1$ and for every $n  \geq 2$, $P_{k}(n)=k\cdot P_k(n-1)+P_k(n-2)$. I want to find:

1-$H_k=\lim_{ n \to \infty }\frac{P_k(n)}{P_k({n-1})}$ and

2-$M=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}({H_k }-k)$

Comment: what is $P$ in your question?

Comment: Thanks you, I edited the quesion @hamidkamali

Comment: Looks like a job for generating functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The characteristic polynomial of $P_k$ is: $$\lambda^2-k\lambda-1=0$$ And so by $P_k(0)=0$ and $P_k(1)=1$ we get that: $$P_k(n)=\frac1{\sqrt{k^2+4}}((\frac{k+\sqrt{k^2+4}}2)^n-(\frac{k-\sqrt{k^2+4}}2)^n)$$ And from here: $$
\begin{align}
\frac{P_k(n)}{P_k(n-1)}&=\frac{(\frac{k+\sqrt{k^2+4}}2)^n-(\frac{k-\sqrt{k^2+4}}2)^n}{(\frac{k+\sqrt{k^2+4}}2)^{n-1}-(\frac{k-\sqrt{k^2+4}}2)^{n-1}}\\
&=\frac{(k+\sqrt{k^2+4})(1-(\frac{k-\sqrt{k^2+4}}{k+\sqrt{k^2+4}})^n)}{2-2(\frac{k-\sqrt{k^2+4}}{k+\sqrt{k^2+4}})^{n-1}}\\
\end{align}
$$
Now, becaus of $|\frac{k-\sqrt{k^2+4}}{k+\sqrt{k^2+4}}|\lt 1$, 
we have $$\lim_{n\to \infty} (\frac{k-\sqrt{k^2+4}}{k+\sqrt{k^2+4}})^n=\lim_{n\to \infty} (\frac{k-\sqrt{k^2+4}}{k+\sqrt{k^2+4}})^{n-1}=0$$ Thus:
$$H_k=\frac{k+\sqrt{k^2+4}}2$$

Comment: I thank to You very much, I don't know why $H_k$ not equal $\frac{k+\sqrt{k^2+4}}{2}$

Comment: I hope you get your answer from above.

Comment: I mean, if $k=1$, then $P_1(n)$ is the  Fibonacci sequence then $H_1$ is golden ratio $\frac{1+\sqrt{1^2+4}}{2}$

 $k=2$ $P_2(n)$ is the  Pell sequence then $H_2$ is silver ratio $\frac{2+\sqrt{2^2+4}}{2}=1+\sqrt{2}$. So may $H_k=\frac{k+\sqrt{k^2+4}}{2}$

I am sorry if I typo

Comment: I'm sorry. I made a mistake. I think it's right now.

Comment: I thank to You very much dear Mister @hamidkamali

Answer (score 1):

The standard method for solving constant coefficient linear recursions says that
$$
P_k(n)=p_k\pi_k^n+m_k\mu_k^n
$$
where
$$
\pi_k=\frac{k+\sqrt{k^2+4}}2\quad\text{and}\quad\mu_k=\frac{k-\sqrt{k^2+4}}2
$$
are roots of $x^2-kx-1=0$.

Since $P_k(0)=0$ and $P_k(1)=1$, we have that $p_k\ne0$. Therefore,
$$
\begin{align}
H_k
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{P_k(n)}{P_k(n-1)}\\
&=\pi_k\\
&=\frac{k+\sqrt{k^2+4}}2
\end{align}
$$

---

$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^\infty(H_k-k)
&=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{-k+\sqrt{k^2+4}}2\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac2{k+\sqrt{k^2+4}}\\
&\ge\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac2{k+\sqrt{k^2+4k+4}}\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{k+1}\\[6pt]
&=\infty
\end{align}
$$
Since the Harmonic Series diverges.